# keras_nlp not recognising tensorflow-gpu

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have `tensorflow-gpu` already installed:

```
>  pip list | grep tensorflow
tensorflow-addons             0.19.0
tensorflow-estimator          2.11.0
tensorflow-gpu                2.11.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.27.0
tensorflow-probability        0.19.0
```

However, when I tried to install `keras_nlp`, it still tries to install the cpu version of tensorflow:

```
>  pip install keras_nlp
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
Collecting keras_nlp
  Downloading keras_nlp-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (337 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 337.5/337.5 kB 5.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py in /home/steven/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from keras_nlp) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /home/steven/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from keras_nlp) (21.3)
Collecting tensorflow
  Downloading tensorflow-2.11.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (588.3 MB)
     ╸━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 13.5/588.3 MB 7.8 MB/s eta 0:01:14
ERROR: Operation cancelled by user
```

Any idea why?

Comment: its not the cpu version of tensorflow, since many releases there is only one package called tensorflow that handles both CPU and GPU, there is no tensorflow-gpu package anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was merged into a single package. Uninstalling tensorflow-gpu and installing the tensorflow meta package worked.